# A question about the behavior of the algebraic curve $y=x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-curves

The algebraic curve  $y=x^n$ shows  steep rise in value as $x$ become closer to 1.

How to find the point at which the steep rise starts?[image]

Comment: What actually is steep rise. It's not defined in terms of maths

Comment: You need to define what "steep rise" means. For example you could ask to find the $x$ value at which $y>0.01$ or some other value. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

What, exactly, is a steep rise?

If you define a steep rise as greater than a slope of $m$,then this is not too hard to find.

For $y=x^n$,the derivative, or tangent slope, at any point is $nx^{n-1}$.

If $nx^{n-1}\geq m$, then $\displaystyle x \geq \sqrt[n-1]{\frac{m}{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

Such a point is not defined, it is a *subjective* concept.

Comment: if you can't run up the hill it's steep

Comment: @SakethMalyala: this is subjective.

Comment: it's just a joke :)

Comment: @SakethMalyala: I commented on the comment that you discarded.

Comment: yes, the one about m=1. i say that because the average person cannot walk up a steeper incline @Yves Daoust